# Handle fractional values (line-height, font-size)

Tags: javascript, css

Recently i found out that webkit do round (actually truncate) when computing styles. Lets say we have `font-size` equal to **14px** and `line-height` to **1.2** so computed `line-height` should be **16.8** and it is in Firefox, but in webkit browsers it's **16**.

I did this fiddle to test this issue across browsers - http://jsfiddle.net/H1D_/KysPm/
Here are results:
[image: webkit]
[image: firefox]

Actually I don't care about rounding. All i need is to have same height of a parent div across browsers. Is there a way to achieve that (other then monitoring actual styles in JS)?

Comment: make sure your ems are worked out to give whole numbers

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: @gvee thx! Interesting but still a have to manually check if calculated `font-size` gives whole numbers after browser computation. 

@Coop The thing is that `font-size` for div is automatically generated (scaling based on user device viewport)